# What is Axis for when constructing WidgetCellSpan

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

What is purpose or use case of qx.ui.virtual.core.Axis when constructing a qx.ui.virtual.layer.WidgetCellSpan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Axis is responsible for mapping screen coordinates to item indexes. Just check out the "test" demo:
http://demo.qooxdoo.org/1.6/demobrowser/index.html?qxenv:demobrowser.withTests:true#virtual~CellSpan.html

But keep in mind that this is experimental code and most likely to change.